# Are piecewise constants in $H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations, trace-map

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a polyhedron.  Denote the faces of $\partial \Omega$ as $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ for some $n$.  Define $u_i\colon \partial\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$u_i(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl} 1 & x\in \mathrm{interior}(e_i)\\ 0 &\mathrm{otherwise} \end{array} \right. .$$

My question is, is $u_i\in H^{1/2}(\partial\Omega)$?  I am interested in knowing the answer, of course, but more interested in a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, piecewise constants are not in $H^{1/2}$. Begin with $d=2$ case: then $u$ is a piecewise constant function on the circle. Its Fourier coefficients $\hat u(n)$ decay like $1/n$ and no faster (either by direct calculation, or considering that $u'$ is a combination of Dirac deltas). Hence, 
$$
\sum_n |n| |\hat u(n)|^2 = \infty
$$ 
A narrow miss; the function is  in $H^s$ for every $s<1/2$.

For the higher dimensional case, one can either use a similar approach replacing the $(d-1)$-dimensional boundary with the torus $\mathbb{T}^{d-1}$, or use a Fubini-type reasoning: if $u$ was in a Sobolev class, its restrictions to almost every line segment crossing a face of $e_i$ would be in the same class. So the answer stays negative.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you explain why you can replace a polygon with a circle?  Some sort of topological argument?

Comment: A polygon can be mapped onto a disk by a bi-Lipschitz map. The composition with such a map preserves the $H^1$ norm up to some factor. Since the $H^{1/2}$ norm is the infimum of the $H^1$ norm of extensions, the result follows.